# How to solve PytestConfigWarning: Unknown config option: DJANGO_ SETTINGS_MODULE error?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I am using django to build my website and I have used django-pytest to test my apps but I have got this error
**Note I am usign python 3.9**

```
================================================================== warnings summary 

===================================================================
..\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:1233
  c:\users\eng_diaa_shalaby\desktop\unittest\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:1233: PytestConfigWarning: Unknown config option: DJANGO_
SETTINGS_MODULE

    self._warn_or_fail_if_strict(f"Unknown config option: {key}\n")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
```

This is my pytest.ini file content

```
# -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = testing_settings
# -- recommended but optional:
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

and I run this command

```
pytest
```

and this is my venv packages

```
Package       Version
------------- -------
asgiref       3.3.4
atomicwrites  1.4.0
attrs         21.2.0
colorama      0.4.4
coverage      5.5
Django        3.2.4
django-pytest 0.2.0
iniconfig     1.1.1
packaging     20.9
pip           21.1.2
pluggy        0.13.1
py            1.10.0
pyparsing     2.4.7
pytest        6.2.4
pytz          2021.1
setuptools    57.0.0
sqlparse      0.4.1
toml          0.10.2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out what was the reason for my problem.
I just uninstall

`django-pytest 0.2.0`

and install

`pytest-django`

instead by running the following command

```
pip install pytest-django
```

and run the following command after pip installed `pytest-django`

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testing.settings
```

And everything just works fine.

Comment: Hm. django-pytest/pytest-django is not the problem. It seems that pytest-django does not respect the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE line in `pytest.ini`, despite the [docs say so](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#step-2-point-pytest-to-your-django-settings)...

Comment: oh, @DIAA SHALABY, and you should remove the whitespace from `DJANGO_ SETTINGS_MODULE`

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer it's not answering OP question neither providing solution.

I have encountered the same problem, I'm using **Django 4.0** and **Pytest 7.2.1**

I'm using **pytest.ini** as configuration file.

Solution:

```
[tool:pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = core.settings.local
python_files = test_*.py
```

Adding keyword **tool** solves the problem.

Another thing that might be necessary is adding ENV variable:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Comment: This just ignores the `pytest` section

Answer (score 3):

The warning

```
PytestConfigWarning: Unknown config option: some-name
```

means that the config option `some-name` is not known to `pytest` or any of the currently installed `pytest` plugins (just what the warning implies). In particular, here it means that either `pytest-django` is not installed, or it is not visible to `pytest` for some reason (e.g. you have installed `pytest-django` using the wrong `pip` command).

To troubleshoot, first list all installed plugins that `pytest` finds using `pytest -VV`:

```
$ pytest -VV
This is pytest version 6.2.5, imported from /private/tmp/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest/__init__.py
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-django-4.5.2 at /private/tmp/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py
  pytest-cov-3.0.0 at /private/tmp/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py
```

Here, `pytest` reports that two plugins are found: `pytest-cov` and `pytest-django`.

Now, if `pytest-django` is not listed, check where it was installed by e.g. issuing `pip show pytest-django` and looking for the path under `Location`:

```
$ pip show pytest-django
...
Location: /private/tmp/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Or, if `pip` is not available for you, check where Python import `pytest_django` package from via

```
$ python -c 'import pytest_django; print(pytest_django.__path__[0])'
/private/tmp/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_django
```

The paths to `site-packages` directory in both outputs should match. In this example, both `pytest -VV` and `pip show pytest-django` report `/private/tmp/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages` as the installation path. If those differ, reinstall `pytest-django` using the correct Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your `pytest.ini` file by removing spaces around `=`:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_project_name.settings
```

Note:
per Django structure, your project should have a subfolder with `settings.py` file in it. You need to point pytest to this file and use dot `.` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In my case I was having an entry `py.test --ignore=outofscope` in my `pytest.ini` file, which was causing that warning.

I solved my problem by updating my `pytest.ini` file.

- look for any warning/error raised by your editor
- remove any extra space when assigning some values

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for some reason `pytest` was not runnin from the currently activated venv